# Remove json object from array of objects in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column `userinventory` in mysql table with below data and I want to remove one of json object where "sellFlag":"y" and "product_id":"1"
`[{
    "price": "250",
    "category": "Furniture",
    "sellFlag": "y",
    "assetLink": "Furniture/Table",
    "product_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "price": "175",
    "category": "Furniture",
    "assetLink": "Furniture/IkeaStockholmCoffeeTableBlack",
    "product_id": "31"
  },
  {
    "price": "300",
    "category": "Furniture",
    "assetLink": "Furniture/ZanottaDamaSofaMultiseater",
    "product_id": "29"
  },
  {
    "price": "200",
    "category": "Furniture",
    "assetLink": "Furniture/RoundTable",
    "product_id": "9"
  }]`

I have tried `select JSON_SEARCH(userInventory,'all','y', NULL,'$[*].sellFlag') as uInvent FROM user_information WHERE user_id=50` its giving result `"$[27].sellFlag"` but I need to add condition for product_id too

After successful removal, below result is required.
`[{
    "price": "175",
    "category": "Furniture",
    "assetLink": "Furniture/IkeaStockholmCoffeeTableBlack",
    "product_id": "31"
  },
  {
    "price": "300",
    "category": "Furniture",
    "assetLink": "Furniture/ZanottaDamaSofaMultiseater",
    "product_id": "29"
  },
  {
    "price": "200",
    "category": "Furniture",
    "assetLink": "Furniture/RoundTable",
    "product_id": "9"
  }]`

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I add two conditions in json_search() ? like in below query `select JSON_SEARCH(userInventory,'all','y', NULL,'$[*].sellFlag') as uInvent FROM user_information`, searching for "$[*].sellFlag" only I want to add condition for product_id as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to collection of objects and then loop them in `foreach`
and test any conditions and remove any object 
and in the end convert it again to json

Comment: This operation need to be done in one of the column in mysql table. I can fetch complete column's value, manipulate and update the column in mysql table but I think its not best practice.

Comment: @Shijin: where is the ` where "sellFlag":"y" and "product_id":"1" ` condition addressed ? Your answer will always remove 0 index value but in my case value is not always in 0 index